# solve Topology error in Grass using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, topology, qgis-grass-plugin

I want to build a raster from a vector layer by using "v.to.raster.attributes" in QGIS but its not working and give me an error to build a topology using v.build. I build it but after that i have no layer to add in qgis using grass plugin. it doesn't give me any error. I am not getting what's actually problem is ?

```
Out put after adding vector layer
"v.in.ogr dsn=D:/Thesis/Data/Mangla_Study_Area/mangla_area_p.shp output=Mangla snap=-1 min_area=0.0001 -o

Over-riding projection check

Layer: mangla_area_p

Counting polygons for 1 features...


Importing map 1 features...

-----------------------------------------------------

Building topology for vector map ...

Registering primitives...

1 primitives registered

54951 vertices registered

Number of nodes: 1

Number of primitives: 1

Number of points: 0

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 1

Number of centroids: 0

Number of areas: -

Number of isles: -

-----------------------------------------------------

￼Cleaning polygons, result is not guaranteed!

-----------------------------------------------------

Break polygons:



-----------------------------------------------------

Remove duplicates:


-----------------------------------------------------

Break boundaries:


-----------------------------------------------------

Remove duplicates:


-----------------------------------------------------

Clean boundaries at nodes:


-----------------------------------------------------

Merge boundaries:


-----------------------------------------------------

Change dangles to lines:


-----------------------------------------------------

Remove bridges:


-----------------------------------------------------

Building topology for vector map ...

Building areas...


1 areas built

1 isles built

Attaching islands...


Number of nodes: 1

Number of primitives: 1

Number of points: 0

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 1

Number of centroids: 0

Number of areas: 1

Number of isles: 1

Number of areas without centroid: 1

-----------------------------------------------------

Find centroids for layer: mangla_area_p

-----------------------------------------------------

Write centroids:


-----------------------------------------------------

1 input polygons

Total area: 2.26321E+008 (1 areas)

Overlapping area: 0 (0 areas)

Area without category: 0 (0 areas)

-----------------------------------------------------

Building topology for vector map ...

Registering primitives...

2 primitives registered

54952 vertices registered

Building areas...


1 areas built

1 isles built

Attaching islands...


Attaching centroids...


Number of nodes: 2

Number of primitives: 2

Number of points: 0

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 1

Number of centroids: 1

Number of areas: 1

Number of isles: 1
Successfully finished"

and after applying topology V.build

"v.build map=Mangla@Mangla_reservior option=build error=Mangla_topology

Building topology for vector map ...

Registering primitives...

2 primitives registered

54952 vertices registered

Building areas...


1 areas built

1 isles built

Attaching islands...


Attaching centroids...


Number of nodes: 2

Number of primitives: 2

Number of points: 0

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 1

Number of centroids: 1

Number of areas: 1

Number of isles: 1

Building topology for vector map ...

Registering primitives...

0 primitives registered

0 vertices registered

Building areas...

0 areas built

0 isles built

Attaching islands...

Attaching centroids...

Number of nodes: 0

Number of primitives: 0

Number of points: 0

Number of lines: 0

Number of boundaries: 0

Number of centroids: 0

Number of areas: 0

Number of isles: 0
Successfully finished"
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without an error message, but your output does not have a file extension (not necessarily a problem, but try adding `.tif` for example). There is also no cellsize given, which might be a problem, although it is flagged as "optional". I would try to assign this. And, once you are already in QGIS, give it a shot with Raster --> Conversion --> Rasterize